How to tackle Propagation delay using Early late gate synchronization?
I am simulating a basic communication system in baseband I'm transmitting QPSK symbols at 2 samples / symbol using RRC for pulse shaping and I have added zeros before the actual symbol for propagation delay modeling. I also added AWGN noise to the transmitted signal. Now I want to do the timing synchronization using Early late gate TED. can anyone tell me how can I approach this ?

This is what I'm referring to but unable to implement this all in lab view however I've Implemented TED but confused about Interpolation control and Interpolator.

The Timing Error Detector produces an error signal based on time offsets between the actual sampling location within a symbol and the ideal sampling location. The loop filter, which can in this case be a simple integrator (accumulator) for a first order loop implementation , will have an appropriate gain coefficient such that the output will appropriately increase or decrease in the presence of timing error to adjust the interpolator, such that the resulting error is driven towards zero. The interpolator therefore is a variable delay device, which based on a linear control value from the loop filter, will adjust (correct) the timing offset.
Farrow Filters and polyphase filters are excellent choices to implement this variable control delay (a simple search on this site will lead to many other posts covering their implementation in more detail).
This is a high level overview, and the complete implementation details would be well beyond what could be captured here in terms of how to implement the fractional delay, how to set the gain of the loop for optimum loop bandwidth and what the considerations for that would be, but hopefully it provides further direction for the OP.

The OP asked a comment in the question about TED for QPSK. I haven't seen this documented elsewhere (it likely is) but came to the conclusion on my own from understanding the fundamental operation of the Gardner TED as an approximation of a maximum likelihood timing detector, as well as since confirmed in operation to be as described below (applicable to both QPSK and QAM):

This is specifically 2 samples per symbol such that we have at any given time "prompt", "early" and "late". Although also be aware that with the Gardner TED "prompt" is at the transition between two symbols and not the "ideal" sample for which to make the symbol decision.
How do I know this? I teach online courses on DSP, and specifically the online course "DSP for Software Radio" where I go into much more detail in the Gardner TED and other timing recovery algorithms, carrier recovery and software receiver implementations and architectures in general. The course is starting up again very soon! More details and to sign up can be found here: dsprelated.com/courses

Thanks Dan, I want to confirm one thing about TED I'm making using this article so the equation here will be same for QPSK too. what I'm doing is error = real(estimated_symbol) * real(late - early) is it right or I have to do some modification there.

See my update, hope that helps!

@Dan_Boschen FWIW, that's the same expression I came up with years ago as an educated guess. https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/2a8b58ca18b5bbd978ca6cd495450c2a9b4ea2b8/gr-digital/lib/timing_error_detector.cc#L297 . It just made sense.

@AndyWalls That's worth a lot! Thanks for letting me know, and yes makes sense. I think we could do further noise reduction normalizations to reduce self-noise in the QAM case...if that noise was even big enough to be a concern.  But yes it makes sense and would lead to an educated guess but knowing I'm not the only one guessing is really good.

Loop filter used here must be PI ?

In my opinion a PI filter is the simplest filter that  can be tuned to provide a decent rate of convergence and good stability when tracking.  It would be hard to tune an integral filter alone to both converge rapidly and not jitter around when tracking.  But you can use any filter you want that doesn't have a long delay.

FWIW The article you linked is about how to synchronize to symbols with only resampling with interpolation without down sampling, to develop a reduced complexity synchronizer.  If you are just learning about PLL symbol synchronization, that might not be the best example to start with for personal discovery experimentation.  Starting with 4-8 samples per symbol on input and having the synchronizer also do the down sampling, will result in simulations that will help you build intuition faster.  The synchronizer will be slightly more complex, but not by much.
